# Finding new co-ordinates by using projections and matrix multiplication.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

### **PART 1**$\def\i{\hat{\imath}} \def\j{\hat{\jmath}} $

Let the standard basis is $\i =   \left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   1  \\
   0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$ and $\j=  \left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   0 \\
   1  \\
  \end{array} } \right]$.

Let $\i$ goes to $ v_1 =  \frac{1}{\sqrt5}\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   2 \\
   1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$ and let $\j$ goes to $ v_2 =  \frac{1}{\sqrt5}\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   -1 \\
   2  \\
  \end{array} } \right]$.

$\implies$ the transformation matrix can be represented by, $ A =\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   v_1 & v_2 \\
  \end{array} } \right] =   \frac{1}{\sqrt5} \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   2 & -1 \\
   1 & 2  \\
  \end{array} } \right]$

after transformation, $a = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1  \\
   1  \\
  \end{array} } \right]$ becomes $Aa = \frac{1}{\sqrt5} \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   2 & -1 \\
   1 & 2  \\
  \end{array} } \right]\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1  \\
   1  \\
  \end{array} } \right] = \frac{1}{\sqrt5}\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1  \\
   3  \\
  \end{array} } \right]$

---

### **PART 2**

Now, look at this figure.[image]

Here $s_{a1} $ and $s_{a2}$ are projections of $a=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1  \\
   1  \\
  \end{array} } \right]$ on $v_1$ and $v_2$, respectively. and $p_{a1} = s_{a1}.v_1$ and $p_{a2} = s_{a2}.v_2$.  Clearly, after transformation by A, $a=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1  \\
   1  \\
  \end{array} } \right]$ becomes $\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   s_{a1}  \\
   s_{a2}  \\
  \end{array} } \right] \implies s_{a1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt5}$  and $s_{a2} = \frac{3}{\sqrt5}$ but $s_{a1} = v_1^T\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1  \\
   1  \\
  \end{array} } \right] =\frac{1}{\sqrt5} \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   2 & 1  \\
  \end{array} } \right]\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1  \\
   1  \\
  \end{array} } \right] = \frac{3}{\sqrt5}$ and similarly, $s_{a2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt5}$

---

Contradiction!
Clearly, I did something wrong in either part 1 or part 2, where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be an approach to consider.  Taking a look at Part 1, it might be useful to consider whether the matrix operation is giving you what you expect using the basis vectors transformed to the new space:

$$
Av_1=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 \\
1 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}
\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

which yields:
$$
\frac{1}{5}
\begin{bmatrix}
3 \\
4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

We would actually expect that the second component be zero, since $v_1$ should be $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$ in the transformed space.

So, now consider $A^T$ as the transformation matrix and repeat the above calculation:

$$
A^Tv_1=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
-1 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}
\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

which yields:
$$
\frac{1}{5}
\begin{bmatrix}
5 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
.

Now considering the test vector $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\\end{bmatrix}$ we get:

$$
A^Ta=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
-1 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
A^Ta=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}
\begin{bmatrix}
3 \\ 
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

which I believe is now consistent with your construction in Part 2.

I hope this helps.